# How To Make The Input Attributes Required In Contact Form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I want to make every input required in the contact form, and I tried using the same logic as what `w3schools` used which is `<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>`

However, it is different in my case, as I do not have the same syntaxes that are being used in the HTML of my contact form.

Here is the code of the contact form:

```css
input[type=text], [type=email], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: rgb(62, 3, 179);
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;    
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index:2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  margin-top:1%;    
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
    
.contactform:hover { 
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column, input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

```html
  <section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="thankyou.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return validForm()">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email..">


            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height: 170px"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How would I make all the fields as "required"? For example, if the user did not complete a required field and they hit the submit button, there should be a message that says that this field is required. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: rgb(62, 3, 179);
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="thankyou.html" method="POST">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>

            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I don't know what you mean by

> I want to make every input required in the contact form, and I tried using the same logic as what w3schools used which is

> However, it is different in my case, as I do not have the same syntaxes that are being used in the HTML of my contact form.

But the `required` works!

Also, your `form action` cannot be a `.html` file!

Answer (score 1):

Add the `required` attribute to each individual `input` inside your `form`. Updated example:

```css
input[type=text], [type=email], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: rgb(62, 3, 179);
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;    
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index:2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  margin-top:1%;    
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
}
    
.contactform:hover { 
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column, input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="thankyou.html" method="POST">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>

            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```